# How to align/adjust colored frames with tables/lists with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, boxes, itemize, columns

I would like to generate coloured frames and align them. But I don't know how to achieve this alignment. How to get rid of extra vertical and horizontal spaces. There should be no gap and no overlapping between the red, green and yellow columns. I tried tcolorboxes and mdframes. But I want to use pure tikz. And the length of the 1st and 2nd row should be equal. And the brackets should be aligned vertically. And the colour in the second table should be extended a little below the last text row and be equal in height for the three columns.[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[neverdecrease]{paralist}
\setdefaultleftmargin{\parindent}{}{}{}{}{}
\usepackage[super]{nth}

\begin{document}
%
% First Tabular / Picture / Blue
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%
% Blue node (sem1): 3 Columns : 7cm | 8 cm | 6 cm
\node [%
rectangle,
shade, 
top    color = blue!1, 
bottom color = blue!10,
inner sep = 0pt,
anchor = north west] (sem1) {%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\vspace{-3mm} % <-- Get rid of this Line?
\begin{tabular}{p{7cm}p{8cm}p{6cm}}
\begin{compactitem}
\item 1.1
\item 1.2
\end{compactitem} &
\begin{compactitem}
\item 1.3
\item 1.4
\end{compactitem} &
\begin{compactitem}
\item 1.5
\item 1.6
\end{compactitem}
\end{tabular}
\vspace{-4mm} % <-- Get rid of this Line?
\end{minipage}
};

% Bracket with (1st)
\coordinate (A) at (sem1.north west);
\coordinate (D) at (sem1.south west);
\coordinate (B) at ($(A) - (0.2,0)$);
\coordinate (C) at ($(D) - (0.2,0)$);
\draw [ultra thick] 
    (A) -- (B) 
    (B) -- node[midway, left] {\nth{1}} (C) 
    (C) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{4mm}
% Second Tabular: Red : Green : Yellow
\begin{tabular}{p{7cm}p{8cm}p{6cm}}
%
% Red Node
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[%
rectangle,
shade, 
top    color = red!12, 
bottom color = red!24,
inner sep = 0pt,
anchor = north west] (sem2red) {%
\parbox{7cm}{%
\begin{center}
\textbf{Red}
\end{center}
\begin{compactitem}
\item R.1
\item R.2
\item R.3
\end{compactitem}}};
%
% Bracket with (2nd)
\coordinate (A) at (sem2red.north west);
\coordinate (D) at (sem2red.south west);
\coordinate (B) at ($(A) - (0.2,0)$);
\coordinate (C) at ($(D) - (0.2,0)$);
\draw [ultra thick] 
    (A) -- (B) 
    (B) -- node[midway, left] {\nth{2}} (C) 
    (C) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture} &
%
% Green Node
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[%
rectangle,
shade, 
top    color = green!12, 
bottom color = green!24,
inner sep = 0pt,
anchor = north west] {%
\parbox{8cm}{%
\begin{center}
\textbf{Green}
\end{center}
\begin{compactitem}
\item G.1
\item G.2
\item G.3
\end{compactitem}}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} &
%
% Yellow Node
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[%
rectangle,
shade, 
top    color = yellow!12, 
bottom color = yellow!24,
inner sep = 0pt,
anchor = north west]{%
\parbox{6cm}{%
\begin{center}
\textbf{Yellow}
\end{center}
\begin{compactitem}
\item Y.1
\item Y.2
\end{compactitem}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution, maybe it's not what you where looking for. I added some `\hspace` and some options in the `\parbox` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[neverdecrease]{paralist}
\setdefaultleftmargin{\parindent}{}{}{}{}{}
\usepackage[super]{nth}

\begin{document}
    %
    % First Tabular / Picture / Blue
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    %
    % Blue node (sem1): 3 Columns : 7cm | 8 cm | 6 cm
    \node [%
    rectangle,
    shade, 
    top    color = blue!1, 
    bottom color = blue!10,
    inner sep = 0pt,
    anchor = north west] (sem1) {%
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \vspace{-3mm} % <-- Get rid of this Line?
        \hspace{-3.5mm} % <-- Added horizontal space
        \begin{tabular}{p{7cm}p{8cm}p{6cm}}
        \begin{compactitem}
        \item 1.1
        \item 1.2
        \end{compactitem} &
        \begin{compactitem}
        \item 1.3
        \item 1.4
        \end{compactitem} &
        \begin{compactitem}
        \item 1.5
        \item 1.6
        \end{compactitem}
        \end{tabular}
        \vspace{-4mm} % <-- Get rid of this Line?
        \end{minipage}
    };

    % Bracket with (1st)
    \coordinate (A) at (sem1.north west);
    \coordinate (D) at (sem1.south west);
    \coordinate (B) at ($(A) - (0.2,0)$);
    \coordinate (C) at ($(D) - (0.2,0)$);
    \draw [ultra thick] 
    (A) -- (B) 
    (B) -- node[midway, left] {\nth{1}} (C) 
    (C) -- (D);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \vspace{4mm}
    \hspace{-3.5mm} % <-- Added horizontal space
    % Second Tabular: Red : Green : Yellow
    \begin{tabular}{p{7cm}p{8cm}p{6cm}}
        %
        % Red Node
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[%
        rectangle,
        shade, 
        top    color = red!12, 
        bottom color = red!24,
        inner sep = 0pt,
        anchor = north west] (sem2red) {%
            \parbox[b][7.5em][t]{7cm}{% <-- added [pos][height][contentpos] options in parbox
                \begin{center}
                \textbf{Red}
                \end{center}
                \begin{compactitem}
                \item R.1
                \item R.2
                \item R.3
                \end{compactitem}}};
        %
        % Bracket with (2nd)
        \coordinate (A) at (sem2red.north west);
        \coordinate (D) at (sem2red.south west);
        \coordinate (B) at ($(A) - (0.2,0)$);
        \coordinate (C) at ($(D) - (0.2,0)$);
        \draw [ultra thick] 
        (A) -- (B) 
        (B) -- node[midway, left] {\nth{2}} (C) 
        (C) -- (D);

        \end{tikzpicture} &
        %
        % Green Node
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[%
        rectangle,
        shade, 
        top    color = green!12, 
        bottom color = green!24,
        inner sep = 0pt,
        anchor = north west] {%
            \parbox[b][7.5em][t]{8cm}{% <-- added [pos][height][contentpos] options in parbox
                \begin{center}
                \textbf{Green}
                \end{center}
                \begin{compactitem}
                \item G.1
                \item G.2
                \item G.3
                \end{compactitem}}}; 
        \end{tikzpicture} &
        %
        % Yellow Node
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[%
        rectangle,
        shade, 
        top    color = yellow!12, 
        bottom color = yellow!24,
        inner sep = 0pt,
        anchor = north west]{%
            \parbox[b][7.5em][t]{8.8cm}{% <-- added [pos][height][contentpos] options in parbox
                \begin{center}
                \textbf{Yellow}
                \end{center}
                \begin{compactitem}
                \item Y.1
                \item Y.2
                \end{compactitem}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is another possible solution, using tikz nodes with `\tikzstyle{}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[neverdecrease]{paralist}
\setdefaultleftmargin{\parindent}{}{}{}{}{}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{bluebox} = [
    shade, 
    top    color = blue!1, 
    bottom color = blue!10,
    rectangle,
    minimum width=.33\textwidth,
    minimum height=.1\textheight,
    outer xsep=2mm,
    inner sep=1mm,anchor = north west]

    \tikzstyle{redbox} = [
    shade, 
    top    color = red!12, 
    bottom color = red!24,
    rectangle,
    minimum width=7cm,
    minimum height=.1\textheight,
    outer xsep=2mm,
    inner xsep=3mm,anchor = north west]

    \tikzstyle{greenbox} = [
    shade, 
    top    color = green!12, 
    bottom color = green!24,
    rectangle,
    minimum width=7cm,
    minimum height=.1\textheight,
    outer xsep=2mm,
    inner xsep=3mm,anchor = north west]

    \tikzstyle{yellowbox} = [
    shade, 
    top    color = yellow!12, 
    bottom color = yellow!24,
    rectangle,
    minimum width=7cm,
    minimum height=.1\textheight,
    outer xsep=2mm,
    inner xsep=3mm,anchor = north west]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [bluebox] (sem1){
            \begin{tabular}{p{7.6cm}p{7.6cm}p{6.9cm}}
            \begin{compactitem}
            \item 1.1
            \item 1.2
            \end{compactitem} &
            \begin{compactitem}
            \item 1.3
            \item 1.4
            \end{compactitem} &
            \begin{compactitem}
            \item 1.5
            \item 1.6
            \end{compactitem}
            \end{tabular}
        };
        % Bracket with (1st)
        \coordinate (A) at (sem1.north west);
        \coordinate (D) at (sem1.south west);
        \coordinate (B) at ($(A) - (0.2,0)$);
        \coordinate (C) at ($(D) - (0.2,0)$);
        \draw [ultra thick] 
        (A) -- (B) 
        (B) -- node[midway, left] {\nth{1}} (C) 
        (C) -- (D);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [redbox] at (0,-1.5) (sem2red){
            \parbox[b][7.5em][t]{7cm}{% <-- added [pos][height][contentpos] options in parbox
                \begin{center}
                \textbf{Red}
                \end{center}
                \begin{compactitem}
                \item R.1
                \item R.2
                \item R.3
                \end{compactitem}}
        };
        \node [greenbox] at (sem2red.north east) (sem3green){
            \parbox[b][7.5em][t]{7cm}{% <-- added [pos][height][contentpos] options in parbox
                \begin{center}
                \textbf{Green}
                \end{center}
                \begin{compactitem}
                \item G.1
                \item G.2
                \item G.3
                \end{compactitem}}
        };
        \node [yellowbox] at (sem3green.north east) (){
            \parbox[b][7.5em][t]{7cm}{% <-- added [pos][height][contentpos] options in parbox
                \begin{center}
                \textbf{Yellow}
                \end{center}
                \begin{compactitem}
                \item Y.1
                \item Y.2
                \end{compactitem}}
        };  

        \coordinate (A) at (sem2red.north west);
        \coordinate (D) at (sem2red.south west);
        \coordinate (B) at ($(A) - (0.2,0)$);
        \coordinate (C) at ($(D) - (0.2,0)$);
        \draw [ultra thick] 
        (A) -- (B) 
        (B) -- node[midway, left] {\nth{2}} (C) 
        (C) -- (D);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**  (simplified syntax)

One pure `tikz` option is to put everything inside a `matrix of nodes` to give:

[image]

The `matrix of nodes` takes care of the alignment of the entries, so you do not need to embed `tabular` environments etc into the nodes, which makes the code relatively compact (modulo the code needed for the left bracket):

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,backgrounds}
\newdimen\topy
\newdimen\boty
\usepackage[super]{nth}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\MyBullet{$\bullet$\space}
\tikzset{%
    % a pic to add a labelled [ to certain rows
    pics/leftbracket/.style args={#1, #2, #3}{
       code = {
         \pgfextracty\topy{\pgfpointanchor{M-#1-1}{north west}}% y-coords of rows
         \pgfextracty\boty{\pgfpointanchor{M-#2-1}{south west}}
         \topy=\dimexpr\topy-\boty+1pt% height of rows
         % draw the delimiter with the correct height
         \node[rectangle, left delimiter={[}, minimum height=\topy]
                at ($ (0,0.5pt)+(M-#1-1.north west)!0.5!(M-#2-1.south west) $){};
         % the label
         \node at ($ (M-#1-1.north west)!0.5!(M-#2-1.south west) $)[left=3mm]{#3};
      }
   },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nobullet/.code={\let\MyBullet\relax},
                    centered/.style={align=center, nobullet},
  ]
  \matrix (M)[matrix of nodes,row sep=0mm,column sep=1mm,
              outer sep=0mm,
              nodes={align=left, text width=0.3\textwidth,
                     execute at begin node=\MyBullet},
    ]{
    1.1 & 1.3  & 1.3\\
    1.2 & 1.4  & 1.6\\[3mm]% extra space between rows
    |[centered]|Red & |[centered]|Green & |[centered]|Yellow\\
    R.1  & G.1 & Y.1\\
    R.2  & G.2 & Y.2\\
    R.3  & G.3 & |[nobullet]|\\
   };
   \pic{leftbracket={1, 2, \nth{1}}};
   \pic{leftbracket={3, 6, \nth{2}}};
   % now draw the background colours using layers
   \begin{scope}[on background layer, rounded corners]
      \fill[top color=blue!0, bottom color=blue!10]
             (M-1-1.north west) rectangle (M-2-3.south east);
      \fill[red!10]    (M-3-1.north west) rectangle (M-6-1.south east);
      \fill[green!20]  (M-3-2.north west) rectangle (M-6-2.south east);
      \fill[yellow!30] (M-3-3.north west) rectangle (M-6-3.south east);
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The trickiest part is drawing the brackets on the left-hand side, which is done using a `pic` that takes three arguments:

```
\pic{leftbracket={index of first row, index of last row, label}
```

This draws a left bracket `[` between the `first` and `last` rows of the matrix with the specified `label`. This code is mostly generic so it should be easy to adapt it to work with other delimiters which could be place on other sides of the matrix.

The rows are coloured by hand after the matrix is drawn using the `backgrounds` library. For the row entries I have used `\MyBullet` and `execute at begin node` to automatically add `$\bullet$\space` to every node. The bullet is "turned" off by the `nobullet` style, which is used in the last row of the yellow section. You could add a counter to `\MyBullet` using `\refstepcounter` if you wanted the "items" to be automatically numbered, but as you are using `compactitem` I suspect that you do not want this.

By default the entries in the `matrix of nodes` are left aligned. I have overridden this for the column  headings in the second row by using `|[centered]|` to apply the `centered` style that is defined at the start of the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the `matrix of nodes` command before. A really cool concise solution. I accepted the other answer because I would like to be able for example to define different `row sep` for the first row (blue box) and the second row (red, green, yellow boxes). But this one will also come handy in next time.

Comment: @Nik It is easy to style different rows differently in a `matrix of nodes`: just use `row 1/.style={...}, row 2/.style={...}`. Other variants are also possible. See section 20.3.3 (page 310) of the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) manual (Version 3.0.1a). You can also use "standard" tableaux commands like `\\[2mm]` to add extra space between rows.

Comment: Again I learned something. Thank you. For what is this command `>=stealth,->,shorten >=2pt`? I don't see any arrows? And just in case you have some more time for an answer: How should one extend the bracket, so that the box is within it? Now the bracket is a bit smaller than the row. Ok, I can manually add some space to `M-#1-1.north west`, etc. but is there a more automatic way?

Comment: @Nik You're right, `>=stealth,->,shorten >=2pt` isn't needed here. I've configured my editor to insert this and I forgot to take it out. Personally, I thought that the bracket was perfect:) If you want to extend it use something like `\topy=\dimexpr\topy-\boty+1pt` and change the following node specification to `(0,0.5pt)+(M-#1-1.north west)!0.5!(M-#2-1.south west)`. I'd also add `rounded corners` as an option to the `scope` environment.

Comment: @Nik I've added those tweaks to the MWE.